# RoR user model to have multiple languages

Tags: mysql, ruby-on-rails, model

I am editing the devise generated User Model to add a language field for the user where he can add one or more languages that he speaks from a ComboBox.

My question is what would be the best way to represent that in mysql. 
I don't know the number of languages that he speaks so it can be up to 20 maybe.

I thought of creating a language Model which contains LanguageId,LanguageName and LanguageCode
and then use has_and_belongs_to_many with the User Model and have a join table of both models.

I am not really sure if this is the right approach for this problem.

Any suggestions?

Comment: create a join table with user_id and language_id

Comment: Yes this seems to be the best approach to do it.

Answer (score 0):

You could also just have a serialized array and store all the chosen languages in a string on your user model.

It depends on how you plan to use the stored language-user data, if you need to use them as a search parameter, then all means you should have a HABTM to represent it.

If you just need to have the data to show on a user show page, and nothing else, storing it on a string or text attribute, and serialize <-> de-serialize when necessary can work, although it may feel strange.

Comment: Actually it is that the user will have more than languages associated with his user mode. So like he has email, password, and languages.
So I am not sure whether the serialized array will be a good option